# Unity. Input in function for UI button OnClick

Tags: unity, c#, gui, input, unityscript

I am trying to create multiple selections for some items on my UI. To perform multiple selections of items I want a user to hold left control button. But then I add

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftControl)){
/* Logic */
}
```

It registers in debugger what LeftControl is pressed but it skips all logic in brackets. This function is public and created for UI button. 
Is Input and Button.OnClick compatible at all?

Comment: Try `Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl)` : will return true every frame while the button is pressed, allowing you to detect the OnClick event. Otherwise, you **need** to press the key the same frame you click on the button (quite hard)

Comment: This solution helped. You can make an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Answer extracted from comment*

With your current code, your user needs to press the key the **same frame** he / she clicks on the UI button, which is quite hard.

Instead, you should simply check if the key is currently pressed by using [Input.GetKey](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html). This function returns `true` **while** the user holds down the key:

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl))
{
   /* Logic */
}
```